# Wrong data from client passes GraphQL validation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo, nestjs

I've made simple CRUD app with React and Apollo client on NestJS server with GraphQL API.

I have this simple Mutations:

```
schema.gql:

type Mutation {
  createUser(input: CreateUserInput!): User! // CreateUserInput type you can see in user.input.ts below
  updateUser(id: ID!, input: UpdateUserInput!): User!
  deleteUser(id: ID!): User!
}
```

---

```
user.input.ts:

import { InputType, Field } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { EmailScalar } from "../email.scalar-type";

@InputType()
export class CreateUserInput {
    // EmailScalar is a custom Scalar GraphQL Type that i took from the internet and it worked well
    @Field(() => EmailScalar)
    readonly email: string;
    @Field()
    readonly name: string;
}
```

"EmailScalar" type checks if "email" input has `*@*.*` format basically

And when i make createUser Query to GraphQL API like this:

[It cannot pass validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KZf8.png)
(because Email type works fine)

---

But when Query sent from client - it passes validation:

[NestJS server log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47E4w.png) (from code below)

```
users.resolver.ts:

@Mutation(() => User)
async createUser(@Args('input') input: CreateUserInput) { // Type from user.input.ts
   Logger.log(input); // log from screenshot, so if it's here it passed validation
   return this.usersService.create(input); // usersService makes requests to MongoDB
}
```

[And it gets into MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gonz.png)

---

Here is client side part:

```
App.tsx:

...

// CreateUserInput class is not imported to App.tsx (it is at server part) but it seems to be fine with it
const ADD_USER = gql`
  mutation AddMutation($input: CreateUserInput!) {
    createUser(input: $input) {
      id
      name
      email
    }
  }
`

function App(props: any) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_USERS);

  const [addUser] = useMutation(
    ADD_USER,
    {
      update: (cache: any, { data: { createUser } }: any) => {
        const { users } = cache.readQuery({ query: GET_USERS });
        cache.writeQuery({
          query: GET_USERS,
          data: {
            users: [createUser, ...users],
          },
        })
      }
    }
  );

...

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :(</p>;

  return <UserTable users={data.users} addUser={addUser} updateUser={updateUser} deleteUser={deleteUser} />;
}
```

Can someone please explain to me, how does client Query passes validation and what have i done wrong?

Even two empty strings can pass through.

Never worked with NestJS, Apollo, React or GraphQL before, so I'm kinda lost.

> For full code: 
>   https://github.com/N238635/nest-react-crud-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your custom scalar's methods are defined:

```
parseValue(value: string): string {
  return value;
}

serialize(value: string): string {
  return value;
}

parseLiteral(ast: ValueNode): string {
  if (ast.kind !== Kind.STRING) {
    throw new GraphQLError('Query error: Can only parse strings got a: ' + ast.kind, [ast]);
  }

  // Regex taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/761555
  var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  if (!re.test(ast.value)) {
    throw new GraphQLError('Query error: Not a valid Email', [ast]);
  }

  return ast.value;
}
```

`parseLiteral` is called when parsing literal values inside the query (i.e. literal strings wrapped in double quotes). `parseValue` is called when parsing variable values. When your client sends the query, it sends the value as a variable, not as a literal value. So `parseValue` is used instead of `parseLiteral`. But your `parseValue` does not do any kind of validation -- you just return the value as-is. You need to implement the validation logic in *both* methods.

It would also be a good idea to implement the `serialize` method so that your scalar can be used for both input and response validation.